# ios Post data to web service

Tags: php, ios

I've been following this [tutorial](http://divcode.blogspot.com/2012/08/connecting-to-php-service-from-ios.html). I've gotten it all working except getting the name inserted into the database. The score inserts just fine. The following is my code in xCode

```
-(void)postData:(NSString *)userName withScore:(NSNumber *)gamesWon
{
// build up the request that is to be sent to the server
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://indie-world.com/iOS/index.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"postValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];
NSLog(@"%@", @"Request set up");

//create data that will be sent in the psot
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setValue:userName forKey:@"name"];
[dictionary setValue:gamesWon forKey:@"score"];
NSLog(@"%@", @"values set up");

// serialize the dictionary data as json
NSData *data = [[dictionary copy] JSONValue];

NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);

[request setHTTPBody:data];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", data.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(!connection)
{
    NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
}
NSLog(@"%@", @"connection granted");
}
```

And here is my code on the php page

```
<?php
/*Simple Service
This is just a simple php script that will return values ,the 
method is selected using the value of HTTP_METHOD
*/
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","iOSDevelopment","IosDevelopment");
// Check connection
if (!$con)
{
echo("Could not connect to web service.");
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("iosDevelopment");

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_METHOD'] === 'postValues'){ 
$body;
/*Sometimes the body data is attached in raw form and is not attached 
to $_POST, this needs to be handled*/

if($_POST == null){
  $handle  = fopen('php://input', 'r');
  $rawData = fgets($handle);
  $body = json_decode($rawData);
}
else
{
    if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["score"]))
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $score = $_POST["score"];
                    // Check to see if the info is all here. return $body to iOS app.
        $body = $_POST;
    }
    else 
    {
        $data['error'] = 'No Post values';
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
 // add to mysql
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `iosdevelopment`.`rw_high_score` (`score`, `name`) VALUES ('$score',     '$name')";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con))
{
    $data['error'] = 'Score was not added';
    echo json_encode($data);
}
$data['scoreAdded'] = $body;
echo json_encode($data);

}
else 
{
$data['error'] = 'The Service you asked for was not recognized';
echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

What am I missing? The echo return both the name and score. I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: what is the data type of name in your database table?

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is in your PHP Script check out this part

```
$data['scoreAdded'] = $body;
echo json_encode($data);
```

I think it should be

```
$data['scoreAdded'] = $body;
echo json_encode($data['scoreAdded']);
```

I don't know why you make it like this anyway hopefully that will help :)

Comment: Its not the echo part. Its the SQL not inserting the name. The score enters just fine. The name doesn't enter into MySQL. Or is the echo executing the inserting into MySQL table?